# Compute the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sin x)^{\sin x}$ using L'Hopital's

Tags: calculus, limits

I needed some help with computing a limit of a function.  I can compute it directly but I'm asked to use L'Hopital's and can't see where to start or how to use it for my function.

My limit expression is:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sin x)^{\sin x}.$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a logarithm first, and notice that $\sin x \ln \sin x = \frac{\ln \sin x}{1/\sin x}$ becomes $$\frac{\cos x / \sin x}{-\cos x / \sin^2 x}.$$

Comment: As you now have it as a fraction, do i compute L'Hopitals on this?

Comment: Why not get rid of $\sin x$ by using $t=\sin x$ and then your limit is equal to $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}t^t$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say the limit is $y$:

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^+} (\sin x)^{\sin x}$$

Let's take the natural log of both sides in order to get rid of the exponentiation:

$$\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0^+} (\sin x)\ln(\sin x)$$

Now, this is a $0\cdot -\infty$ expression, which is indeterminate, but not a fraction where we can apply L'Hopital's rule. One really easy way to get this kind of expression into a fraction is by changing $\sin x$ into $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}$:

$$\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}\ln(\sin x)=\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}$$

Now, we have a $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ expression, so we can apply L'Hopital's. Take the derivative of both the numerator and denominator:

$$\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{\frac{-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}}$$

Simplify the fraction:

$$\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0^+} -\sin x=-\sin 0=0$$

Thus, since $\ln y=0$, we find that $y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using *T.Bongers* hint we are first of all left with the following

> $$\log(L)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin(x)\log(\sin x)$$

Approaching zero from the RHS we can conclude that the sine term tends to $0$ whereas the logarithmic term tends to negative infinity. Hence we are forced to establish the form $\frac\infty\infty$ to use L'Hospitals rule we may rewrite the product as a fraction which fulfills the given condititons

$$\begin{align*}
\log(L)&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin(x)\log(\sin x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(\sin x)}{1/\sin(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cot(x)}{-1\cot(x)/\sin(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}-\sin(x)\\
\log(L)&=0
\end{align*}$$

> $$\therefore~L=1$$